# How can I select only one card to be flipped instead of multiple cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have made a card component and when I hover over the selected card, all cards rotate.  I know it has to do with using one state for all the cards but I am new to react and can't understand how to solve the issue.

```
const [isFlipped, setIsFlipped] = useState(false);


return (
    <>
      {teams.map((team) => (
        <div
          className={styles.about_us_card}
          key={team.id}
          onMouseEnter={setIsFlipped(!isFlipped)}
        >
          <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
            <div className={styles.about_us_profile_image}>
              <img src="/placeholder.jpeg" alt="profile" />
            </div>
            <div
              className={styles.about_us_profile_info}
              onMouseLeave={handleFlip}
            >
              <div className={styles.about_us_profile_name}>
                <p className={styles.profile_name}>{team.name}</p>
                <p className={styles.profile_job_title}>{team.title}</p>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.about_us_profile_text}>
                <p>{team.about}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ReactCardFlip>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
const [flipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);


return (
    <>
      {teams.map((team) => (
        <div
          className={styles.about_us_card}
          key={team.id}
          onMouseEnter={() => setFlipped(team.id)}
        >
          <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={flipped === team.id} flipDirection="horizontal">
            <div className={styles.about_us_profile_image}>
              <img src="/placeholder.jpeg" alt="profile" />
            </div>
            <div
              className={styles.about_us_profile_info}
              onMouseLeave={handleFlip}
            >
              <div className={styles.about_us_profile_name}>
                <p className={styles.profile_name}>{team.name}</p>
                <p className={styles.profile_job_title}>{team.title}</p>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.about_us_profile_text}>
                <p>{team.about}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ReactCardFlip>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Awesome,  thank you so much.  This works perfectly and I will be taking your advice about moving it into another component. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I would move everything inside the map into another component like this. In this way you can pass `team` with `props` and keep `state` inside the component without checking id or something

*Your component*

```
return (
    <>
      {teams.map((team) => (
         <NewComponent team={team} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

*NewComponent*

```
  const NewComponent = ({team}) => { 
    
    const [isFlipped, setIsFlipped] = useState(false);
    
    
    return (
        <>
          {teams.map((team) => (
            <div
              className={styles.about_us_card}
              key={team.id}
              onMouseEnter={setIsFlipped(!isFlipped)}
            >
              <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
                <div className={styles.about_us_profile_image}>
                  <img src="/placeholder.jpeg" alt="profile" />
                </div>
                <div
                  className={styles.about_us_profile_info}
                  onMouseLeave={handleFlip}
                >
                  <div className={styles.about_us_profile_name}>
                    <p className={styles.profile_name}>{team.name}</p>
                    <p className={styles.profile_job_title}>{team.title}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className={styles.about_us_profile_text}>
                    <p>{team.about}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ReactCardFlip>
            </div>
          ))}
    </>
}
```